# Thread synchronization in C# using Monitor Wait/Pulse

Tags: c#

I have a multi-threaded project in C# that I'm working on, and my idea for controlling the worker thread is not working out as easily as I hoped.

A thread is created when the main GUI window is launched, here is the function it is running:

```
    private void continueReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                while (!startDAQ)
                    Monitor.Wait(_lock);
                startDAQ = false;
                logging = true;

                daqTaskComponent1.ReadAsync();
            }
        }

    }
```

Now, when a button is clicked on the GUI, startDAQ is set to true, and _lock is pulsed to start the thread calling ReadAsync().

On the Async's callback function, I lock the same _lock object and perform some calculations, then set startDAQ to true and pulse again.

This allows my Async function to be called only when the callback is ready to process more data, and that's how it needs to be.

The problem is I need to be able to pause data collection safely, by causing the continueReading thread to pause on the Monitor.Wait and by allowing a callback to complete if ReadAsync has been called before pausing.

This is the code I'm running when the user clicks the button again to pause data collection:

```
    lock (_lock)
    {
        startDAQ = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        while (logging)
            Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    }
```

This isn't working correctly and I'm getting some deadlocks. This is my first time using Monitor and Wait/Pulsing to signal between threads, so I've been a little stumped, and have a feeling there's an easier way to handle this. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is the relevant code from the callback function:

```
    lock (_lock)
    {
        //Lots of code here that just manipulates the data passed to the callback
        startDAQ = true;
        logging = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
    }
```

Added the logging boolean that I forgot when I originally pasted my code.

Comment: Please explain what your problem is. Trying to get a propably wrong workaround running can be pain in the ass.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting deadlocks on my current code. I'm not sure how I can cause a thread running a loop to pause safely. I want the user to be able to click a button to start and stop the thread that's calling ReadAsync. When the user stops the thread I have to perform some cleanup that will cause problems with the callback function, which is why I need any pending ReadAsync's to finish before that cleanup happens.

Comment: startDAQ must be declared *volatile*.

Comment: I tried declaring both startDAQ and logging as volatile and it didn't seem to help any. I've seen it get stuck trying to lock when the user clicks the button again, and I've seen it get stuck on the Monitor.Wait() inside that lock after it gets to while(logging).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply call `ReadAsync` from the GUI thread (Since it is already asynchronous), then call it again from the completion callback. No other (explicit) threads or synchronization needed.

Comment: I guess I never really understood in which context callbacks were being performed. Are they in a new thread? Just don't see how I would interrupt the calling process once it starts so that the user could pause data collection.

Comment: The callback will be in the context of a thread pool thread. To interrupt, signal the completion callback to not call `ReadAsync` again. I would recommend you do this with a `ManualResetEvent`. In the callback, wait on the event with a timeout of 0. If the wait fails, don't call `ReadAsync` again.

Comment: I tried your suggestion out and it works just fine when starting, but I still have an issue stopping. The event handler for my button completes and cleans up objects before the async callback completes and causes some null reference errors. I tried setting up another event which is set only when the callback completes, but I guess the event handler and callback are executing on the same thread, because once I set the event handler to wait for the callback, it deadlocks.